# Turn the json response of an httr GET into a dataframe in R

Tags: r, json, httr, fromjson

Hi I used the `httr` library to get some data from an API. Using this code

```
URL <- "https://spotpet.api.hasoffers.com/Apiv3/json?NetworkToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&Target=Report&Method=getStats&fields[]=Stat.date&fields[]=Stat.offer_id&fields[]=Stat.affiliate_id&fields[]=Affiliate.company&fields[]=Stat.impressions&fields[]=Stat.unique_clicks&fields[]=Stat.suspicious_clicks&fields[]=Stat.conversions&fields[]=Stat.gross_clicks&fields[]=Stat.payout&fields[]=Stat.revenue&fields[]=Stat.source&fields[]=Stat.sale_amount&filters[Stat.date][conditional]=GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO&filters[Stat.date][values]=2020-12-01&totals=0"

data <- GET(URL)
```

if I was getting a csv file I was able to turn it into a dataframe with this code

```
new_data <- read.csv(text=content(data, type = "text", encoding="UTF-8"))
```

but this time the response is in json format

how would I change this code to turn the json content into a dataframe?

here is the json response, sorry it is long but want to post it all so you guys can try it

the results of

dput(content(data))

```
list(request = list(Target = "Report", Format = "json", Service = "HasOffers", 
Version = "2", NetworkToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
Method = "getStats", fields = list("Stat.date", "Stat.offer_id", 
    "Stat.affiliate_id", "Affiliate.company", "Stat.impressions", 
    "Stat.unique_clicks", "Stat.suspicious_clicks", "Stat.conversions", 
    "Stat.gross_clicks", "Stat.payout", "Stat.revenue", "Stat.source", 
    "Stat.sale_amount"), filters = list(Stat.date = list(
    conditional = "GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO", values = "2020-12-01")), 
totals = "0"), response = list(status = 1L, httpStatus = 200L, 
data = list(page = 1L, current = 50L, count = 16901L, pageCount = 339L, 
    data = list(list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "18", 
        affiliate_id = "2", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "1", 
        suspicious_clicks = "0", conversions = "0", gross_clicks = "1", 
        payout = "0.00000", revenue = "0.00000", source = "leadday0quoteform", 
        sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(company = "SPOT INTERNAL EMAIL")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "18", 
            affiliate_id = "29", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "1", 
            suspicious_clicks = "0", conversions = "0", gross_clicks = "1", 
            payout = "0.00000", revenue = "0.00000", source = "FB3.14", 
            sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(company = "Spot Pet Facebook")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "18", 
            affiliate_id = "30", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "5", 
            suspicious_clicks = "0", conversions = "4", gross_clicks = "7", 
            payout = "4.00000", revenue = "0.00000", source = "CMBIO", 
            sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(company = "Spot Pet Instagram")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "18", 
            affiliate_id = "41", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "1", 
            suspicious_clicks = "0", conversions = "2", gross_clicks = "1", 
            payout = "0.00000", revenue = "0.00000", source = "CesarArc", 
            sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(company = "Kendago")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "18", 
            affiliate_id = "41", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "2", 
            suspicious_clicks = "0", conversions = "4", gross_clicks = "3", 
            payout = "2.00000", revenue = "0.00000", source = "CesarArcCTA5", 
            sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(company = "Kendago")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "18", 
            affiliate_id = "279", impressions = "51", unique_clicks = "0", 
            suspicious_clicks = "0", conversions = "0", gross_clicks = "0", 
            payout = "0.00000", revenue = "0.00000", source = "", 
            sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(company = "Cornelius Advisory Services")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "18", 
            affiliate_id = "287", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "20", 
            suspicious_clicks = "7", conversions = "12", 
            gross_clicks = "27", payout = "12.00000", revenue = "0.00000", 
            source = "", sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(
            company = "Cesarsway.com")), list(Stat = list(
            date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "18", affiliate_id = "287", 
            impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "20", suspicious_clicks = "0", 
            conversions = "0", gross_clicks = "20", payout = "0.00000", 
            revenue = "0.00000", source = "CM-EM", sale_amount = "0.00000"), 
            Affiliate = list(company = "Cesarsway.com")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "18", 
            affiliate_id = "287", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "17", 
            suspicious_clicks = "0", conversions = "0", gross_clicks = "17", 
            payout = "0.00000", revenue = "0.00000", source = "cesarsway", 
            sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(company = "Cesarsway.com")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "18", 
            affiliate_id = "287", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "23", 
            suspicious_clicks = "2", conversions = "9", gross_clicks = "25", 
            payout = "8.00000", revenue = "0.00000", source = "cwemailindoctrination1", 
            sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(company = "Cesarsway.com")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "18", 
            affiliate_id = "287", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "25", 
            suspicious_clicks = "0", conversions = "4", gross_clicks = "26", 
            payout = "4.00000", revenue = "0.00000", source = "cwemailindoctrination2", 
            sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(company = "Cesarsway.com")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "18", 
            affiliate_id = "289", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "1", 
            suspicious_clicks = "0", conversions = "0", gross_clicks = "1", 
            payout = "0.00000", revenue = "0.00000", source = "partnerslogo", 
            sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(company = "WoofTrax")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "18", 
            affiliate_id = "312", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "1", 
            suspicious_clicks = "0", conversions = "0", gross_clicks = "1", 
            payout = "0.00000", revenue = "0.00000", source = "", 
            sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(company = "Benefit Hub")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "18", 
            affiliate_id = "312", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "11", 
            suspicious_clicks = "6", conversions = "22", 
            gross_clicks = "28", payout = "12.00000", revenue = "0.00000", 
            source = "EB.BenefitHub", sale_amount = "29.41000"), 
            Affiliate = list(company = "Benefit Hub")), list(
            Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "18", 
              affiliate_id = "319", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "1", 
              suspicious_clicks = "1", conversions = "0", 
              gross_clicks = "1", payout = "0.00000", revenue = "0.00000", 
              source = "EB.ARO", sale_amount = "0.00000"), 
            Affiliate = list(company = "ARO")), list(Stat = list(
            date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "18", affiliate_id = "335", 
            impressions = "1", unique_clicks = "0", suspicious_clicks = "0", 
            conversions = "0", gross_clicks = "0", payout = "0.00000", 
            revenue = "0.00000", source = "", sale_amount = "0.00000"), 
            Affiliate = list(company = "Rich Kleiner")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "18", 
            affiliate_id = "336", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "2", 
            suspicious_clicks = "0", conversions = "0", gross_clicks = "2", 
            payout = "0.00000", revenue = "0.00000", source = "", 
            sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(company = "Spot the Rescue")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "18", 
            affiliate_id = "343", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "1", 
            suspicious_clicks = "0", conversions = "2", gross_clicks = "1", 
            payout = "0.00000", revenue = "0.00000", source = "EB.Insperity", 
            sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(company = "Insperity")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "18", 
            affiliate_id = "348", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "2", 
            suspicious_clicks = "0", conversions = "3", gross_clicks = "2", 
            payout = "2.00000", revenue = "0.00000", source = "EB.Abenity", 
            sale_amount = "38.00000"), Affiliate = list(company = "Abenity")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "18", 
            affiliate_id = "367", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "1", 
            suspicious_clicks = "1", conversions = "0", gross_clicks = "4", 
            payout = "0.00000", revenue = "0.00000", source = "", 
            sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(company = "Tarek")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "18", 
            affiliate_id = "373", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "24", 
            suspicious_clicks = "6", conversions = "49", 
            gross_clicks = "34", payout = "126.00000", revenue = "0.00000", 
            source = "eb.perkspot", sale_amount = "130.42000"), 
            Affiliate = list(company = "PerkSpot")), list(
            Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "18", 
              affiliate_id = "394", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "1", 
              suspicious_clicks = "0", conversions = "4", 
              gross_clicks = "1", payout = "2.00000", revenue = "0.00000", 
              source = "", sale_amount = "61.30000"), Affiliate = list(
              company = "Vcheck Global")), list(Stat = list(
            date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "21", affiliate_id = "298", 
            impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "32", suspicious_clicks = "5", 
            conversions = "20", gross_clicks = "34", payout = "160.00000", 
            revenue = "0.00000", source = "", sale_amount = "167.43000"), 
            Affiliate = list(company = "Benzinga")), list(
            Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "21", 
              affiliate_id = "320", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "135", 
              suspicious_clicks = "14", conversions = "74", 
              gross_clicks = "178", payout = "945.00000", 
              revenue = "0.00000", source = "ConsumerVoice", 
              sale_amount = "128.58000"), Affiliate = list(
              company = "Consumer Voice")), list(Stat = list(
            date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "21", affiliate_id = "332", 
            impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "68", suspicious_clicks = "1", 
            conversions = "57", gross_clicks = "74", payout = "221.00000", 
            revenue = "0.00000", source = "", sale_amount = "157.04000"), 
            Affiliate = list(company = "Ad Practitioners, LLC")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "21", 
            affiliate_id = "357", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "6", 
            suspicious_clicks = "1", conversions = "3", gross_clicks = "10", 
            payout = "18.00000", revenue = "0.00000", source = "", 
            sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(company = "Ad Practitioners, LLC  2")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "21", 
            affiliate_id = "358", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "95", 
            suspicious_clicks = "6", conversions = "24", 
            gross_clicks = "117", payout = "308.75000", revenue = "0.00000", 
            source = "", sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(
            company = "Ad Practitioners, LLC 3")), list(Stat = list(
            date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "21", affiliate_id = "385", 
            impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "5", suspicious_clicks = "1", 
            conversions = "4", gross_clicks = "5", payout = "20.00000", 
            revenue = "0.00000", source = "", sale_amount = "0.00000"), 
            Affiliate = list(company = "Apollo Interactive")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "22", 
            affiliate_id = "292", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "150", 
            suspicious_clicks = "19", conversions = "106", 
            gross_clicks = "177", payout = "1326.00000", 
            revenue = "0.00000", source = "", sale_amount = "310.47000"), 
            Affiliate = list(company = "Natural Intelligence")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "22", 
            affiliate_id = "292", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "0", 
            suspicious_clicks = "0", conversions = "0", gross_clicks = "3", 
            payout = "0.00000", revenue = "0.00000", source = "naturalint", 
            sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(company = "Natural Intelligence")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "22", 
            affiliate_id = "295", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "35", 
            suspicious_clicks = "2", conversions = "22", 
            gross_clicks = "41", payout = "315.00000", revenue = "0.00000", 
            source = "", sale_amount = "52.54000"), Affiliate = list(
            company = "Better Impression")), list(Stat = list(
            date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "22", affiliate_id = "295", 
            impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "0", suspicious_clicks = "0", 
            conversions = "0", gross_clicks = "1", payout = "0.00000", 
            revenue = "0.00000", source = "betterim", sale_amount = "0.00000"), 
            Affiliate = list(company = "Better Impression")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "22", 
            affiliate_id = "297", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "312", 
            suspicious_clicks = "37", conversions = "229", 
            gross_clicks = "353", payout = "4460.00000", 
            revenue = "0.00000", source = "", sale_amount = "331.24000"), 
            Affiliate = list(company = "Search Vision")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "22", 
            affiliate_id = "297", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "0", 
            suspicious_clicks = "0", conversions = "0", gross_clicks = "1", 
            payout = "0.00000", revenue = "0.00000", source = "searchvision", 
            sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(company = "Search Vision")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "22", 
            affiliate_id = "301", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "299", 
            suspicious_clicks = "8", conversions = "176", 
            gross_clicks = "402", payout = "2550.00000", 
            revenue = "0.00000", source = "", sale_amount = "516.91000"), 
            Affiliate = list(company = "Wickfire")), list(
            Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "22", 
              affiliate_id = "301", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "0", 
              suspicious_clicks = "0", conversions = "0", 
              gross_clicks = "1", payout = "0.00000", revenue = "0.00000", 
              source = "wickfire", sale_amount = "0.00000"), 
            Affiliate = list(company = "Wickfire")), list(
            Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "22", 
              affiliate_id = "302", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "1", 
              suspicious_clicks = "0", conversions = "0", 
              gross_clicks = "1", payout = "0.00000", revenue = "0.00000", 
              source = "", sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(
              company = "365 Pet Insurance")), list(Stat = list(
            date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "22", affiliate_id = "302", 
            impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "5", suspicious_clicks = "0", 
            conversions = "4", gross_clicks = "5", payout = "36.00000", 
            revenue = "0.00000", source = "365", sale_amount = "0.00000"), 
            Affiliate = list(company = "365 Pet Insurance")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "22", 
            affiliate_id = "317", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "2", 
            suspicious_clicks = "0", conversions = "2", gross_clicks = "2", 
            payout = "4.00000", revenue = "0.00000", source = "eb.bennie", 
            sale_amount = "29.58000"), Affiliate = list(company = "Bennie")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "22", 
            affiliate_id = "324", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "233", 
            suspicious_clicks = "15", conversions = "113", 
            gross_clicks = "251", payout = "1887.00000", 
            revenue = "0.00000", source = "", sale_amount = "107.60000"), 
            Affiliate = list(company = "LendEDU")), list(
            Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "22", 
              affiliate_id = "326", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "43", 
              suspicious_clicks = "2", conversions = "4", 
              gross_clicks = "44", payout = "60.00000", revenue = "0.00000", 
              source = "", sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(
              company = "Consumer Affairs")), list(Stat = list(
            date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "22", affiliate_id = "326", 
            impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "0", suspicious_clicks = "0", 
            conversions = "0", gross_clicks = "1", payout = "0.00000", 
            revenue = "0.00000", source = "consumeraffairs", 
            sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(company = "Consumer Affairs")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "22", 
            affiliate_id = "331", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "149", 
            suspicious_clicks = "12", conversions = "69", 
            gross_clicks = "185", payout = "1254.00000", 
            revenue = "0.00000", source = "", sale_amount = "142.65000"), 
            Affiliate = list(company = "How Stuff Works")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "22", 
            affiliate_id = "331", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "0", 
            suspicious_clicks = "0", conversions = "0", gross_clicks = "1", 
            payout = "0.00000", revenue = "0.00000", source = "hsw", 
            sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(company = "How Stuff Works")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "22", 
            affiliate_id = "334", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "104", 
            suspicious_clicks = "5", conversions = "72", 
            gross_clicks = "116", payout = "700.00000", revenue = "0.00000", 
            source = "", sale_amount = "69.08000"), Affiliate = list(
            company = "Natural Intelligence MOBILE")), list(
            Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "22", 
              affiliate_id = "351", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "3", 
              suspicious_clicks = "0", conversions = "1", 
              gross_clicks = "3", payout = "10.00000", revenue = "0.00000", 
              source = "EB.AccessPerks", sale_amount = "0.00000"), 
            Affiliate = list(company = "Access Development")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "22", 
            affiliate_id = "363", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "444", 
            suspicious_clicks = "19", conversions = "228", 
            gross_clicks = "475", payout = "1135.00000", 
            revenue = "0.00000", source = "", sale_amount = "48.06000"), 
            Affiliate = list(company = "Natural Intelligence FB")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "22", 
            affiliate_id = "365", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "17", 
            suspicious_clicks = "0", conversions = "4", gross_clicks = "17", 
            payout = "28.00000", revenue = "0.00000", source = "", 
            sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(company = "The Super Collies")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "23", 
            affiliate_id = "290", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "18", 
            suspicious_clicks = "1", conversions = "9", gross_clicks = "20", 
            payout = "100.00000", revenue = "0.00000", source = "", 
            sale_amount = "34.39000"), Affiliate = list(company = "Pets Rule LLC")), 
        list(Stat = list(date = "2020-12-01", offer_id = "26", 
            affiliate_id = "267", impressions = "0", unique_clicks = "1", 
            suspicious_clicks = "0", conversions = "0", gross_clicks = "1", 
            payout = "0.00000", revenue = "0.00000", source = "spoteb", 
            sale_amount = "0.00000"), Affiliate = list(company = "Spot Employee Benefits"))), 
    dbSource = "branddb"), errors = list(), errorMessage = NULL))
```

when I do this piece of code I get this response

```
test <- rjson::fromJSON(httr::content(data, type = 'text'))
test


$response$data$data[[50]]
$response$data$data[[50]]$Stat
$response$data$data[[50]]$Stat$date
[1] "2020-12-01"

$response$data$data[[50]]$Stat$offer_id
[1] "26"

$response$data$data[[50]]$Stat$affiliate_id
[1] "267"

$response$data$data[[50]]$Stat$impressions
[1] "0"

$response$data$data[[50]]$Stat$unique_clicks
[1] "1"

$response$data$data[[50]]$Stat$suspicious_clicks
[1] "0"

$response$data$data[[50]]$Stat$conversions
[1] "0"

$response$data$data[[50]]$Stat$gross_clicks
[1] "1"

$response$data$data[[50]]$Stat$payout
[1] "0.00000"

$response$data$data[[50]]$Stat$revenue
[1] "0.00000"

$response$data$data[[50]]$Stat$source
[1] "spoteb"

$response$data$data[[50]]$Stat$sale_amount
[1] "0.00000"


$response$data$data[[50]]$Affiliate
$response$data$data[[50]]$Affiliate$company
[1] "Spot Employee Benefits"
```

if I do this piece of code I get this response

```
test2 <- test$response$data$data
lapply(test2, list2DF)

         Stat     Affiliate
1  2020-12-01 Pets Rule LLC
2          23 Pets Rule LLC
3         290 Pets Rule LLC
4           0 Pets Rule LLC
5          18 Pets Rule LLC
6           1 Pets Rule LLC
7           9 Pets Rule LLC
8          20 Pets Rule LLC
9   100.00000 Pets Rule LLC
10    0.00000 Pets Rule LLC
11            Pets Rule LLC
12   34.39000 Pets Rule LLC

[[50]]
         Stat              Affiliate
1  2020-12-01 Spot Employee Benefits
2          26 Spot Employee Benefits
3         267 Spot Employee Benefits
4           0 Spot Employee Benefits
5           1 Spot Employee Benefits
6           0 Spot Employee Benefits
7           0 Spot Employee Benefits
8           1 Spot Employee Benefits
9     0.00000 Spot Employee Benefits
10    0.00000 Spot Employee Benefits
11     spoteb Spot Employee Benefits
12    0.00000 Spot Employee Benefits
```

its closer to what I need but not there yet

if I run just run test2 I get this

```
[[50]]
[[50]]$Stat
[[50]]$Stat$date
[1] "2020-12-01"

[[50]]$Stat$offer_id
[1] "26"

[[50]]$Stat$affiliate_id
[1] "267"

[[50]]$Stat$impressions
[1] "0"

[[50]]$Stat$unique_clicks
[1] "1"

[[50]]$Stat$suspicious_clicks
[1] "0"

[[50]]$Stat$conversions
[1] "0"

[[50]]$Stat$gross_clicks
[1] "1"

[[50]]$Stat$payout
[1] "0.00000"

[[50]]$Stat$revenue
[1] "0.00000"

[[50]]$Stat$source
[1] "spoteb"

[[50]]$Stat$sale_amount
[1] "0.00000"


[[50]]$Affiliate
[[50]]$Affiliate$company
[1] "Spot Employee Benefits"
```

the ideal result would be

```
            stats columns                   affiliate column
date        offer_id affiliate_id......     Affiliate company
2020-12-01    26        267  .........       Spot Employee Benefits
.
.
.
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the `length(test)`? in my end it shows 2.

Comment: @Onyambu in my end it also shows 2

Comment: Then `lapply(test, list2DF)` should work

Comment: @Onyambu I get this error following your last suggestion:  Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : cannot replicate NULL to a non-zero length

Comment: Why did you delete your original question and are asking the same thing again?

Comment: @deschen still no luck,  I tried your code with the 2 things I have,  'test' and 'data' and that where my response is stored, 'test' contains a list and 'data' contains the result I pasted at the end of the question,  I tried this 'my_data <- jsonlite::fromJSON(test)$response$data$data' and also 'my_data <- jsonlite::fromJSON(data)$response$data$data'  and I got this error,  Error: Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file

Comment: What is the exact name of the object you stored your response to, i.e. where do you have this long `{"request":{"Target":"Report","Format":"json","Service…` thing?

Comment: @deschen I copied and pasted that from the webpage response when I paste the URL in the browser,  when I do it with code, I first get that object called data that you see at the top in the code, that is a list of 10, from there I run the code 'test <- rjson::fromJSON(httr::content(data, type = 'text'))' and I end with the code you see at the bottom.   I am adding more edits to the question, your suggestion did got me a little bit closer to what I need but still not there,  but to your question the long line is a copy from the webpage response, so that text exactly I dont have it.

Comment: I don't understand why the error. It works on my end

Comment: Can you post the result of `dput(content(data))`?

Comment: And you say my answer got you a bit closer. So waht did you have now as your „temporary“ result and what exactly should your ideal result look like? Not only describe, please show it as code what you‘d expext.

Comment: What if you don‘t run this last line with lapply? Justcthe line with test2?

Comment: And again. Show us how you exactly you want your result to look like?

Comment: And also: 
Can you post the result of dput(content(data))?

Comment: @deschen I added the ideal output, does not need to be exact but something I can later covert to that, right now I dont see column names and I also pasted the output you wanted

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is exactly the reason why a reproducible example with `dput` along with the expected outcome is ALWAYS helpful. You can do:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rrapply)

response <- content(data)

my_data <- rrapply(response$response$data$data, how = "melt") %>%
  select(-L2) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = L3,
              values_from = value) %>%
  select(-L1)
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 50 x 13
   date       offer_id affiliate_id impressions unique_clicks suspicious_clicks conversions gross_clicks payout   revenue source                   sale_amount company    
   <chr>      <chr>    <chr>        <chr>       <chr>         <chr>             <chr>       <chr>        <chr>    <chr>   <chr>                    <chr>       <chr>      
 1 2020-12-01 18       2            0           1             0                 0           1            0.00000  0.00000 "leadday0quoteform"      0.00000     SPOT INTER~
 2 2020-12-01 18       29           0           1             0                 0           1            0.00000  0.00000 "FB3.14"                 0.00000     Spot Pet F~
 3 2020-12-01 18       30           0           5             0                 4           7            4.00000  0.00000 "CMBIO"                  0.00000     Spot Pet I~
 4 2020-12-01 18       41           0           1             0                 2           1            0.00000  0.00000 "CesarArc"               0.00000     Kendago    
 5 2020-12-01 18       41           0           2             0                 4           3            2.00000  0.00000 "CesarArcCTA5"           0.00000     Kendago    
 6 2020-12-01 18       279          51          0             0                 0           0            0.00000  0.00000 ""                       0.00000     Cornelius ~
 7 2020-12-01 18       287          0           20            7                 12          27           12.00000 0.00000 ""                       0.00000     Cesarsway.~
 8 2020-12-01 18       287          0           20            0                 0           20           0.00000  0.00000 "CM-EM"                  0.00000     Cesarsway.~
 9 2020-12-01 18       287          0           17            0                 0           17           0.00000  0.00000 "cesarsway"              0.00000     Cesarsway.~
10 2020-12-01 18       287          0           23            2                 9           25           8.00000  0.00000 "cwemailindoctrination1" 0.00000     Cesarsway.~
# ... with 40 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
response <- GET(URL) %>%
    content()

tibble(response) %>%
  unnest_wider(response) ### purrr package
```

This has been the fastest route for me, although it's prone to errors, especially if there are `NA`s. Unless you explicitly define the column type of your tibble like this.

```
response %>% {
  tibble(
    Target = map_chr(Target, .default = NA),
    Format = map_chr(Format, .default = NA),
    Service = map_chr(Service, .default = NA),
    ... other columns here ...
    data = map(data, .default = NA),
    errors = map_lgl(errors, .default = NA),
    errorMessage = map(errorMessage, .default = NA),
  )
}
```